# UserMailerTest Expected "noreply@example.com" Actual: from@example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I fix this? I'm new to Rails

2) Failure:
UserMailerTest#test_password_reset [/Users/user/Documents/RoR/workspace/sample_app/test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:23]:
Expected: ["noreply@example.com"]
  Actual: ["from@example.com"]

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Password reset"
  end
end
```

>

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.name,               mail.body.encoded
    assert_match user.activation_token,   mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end

  test "password_reset" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.reset_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.password_reset(user)
    assert_equal "Password reset", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from          #this is line 23
    assert_match user.reset_token,        mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```

I changed the "noreply@example.com" to "from@example.com".
Now, it creates another error.

```
  1) Failure:
UserMailerTest#test_account_activation [/Users/lldm0033/Documents/RoR/workspace/sample_app/test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:12]:
Expected /Michael\ Example/ to match "\r\n----==_mimepart_5534d70b387f1_b853fc04845e6cc9478e\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\nUserMailer#account_activation\r\n\r\n, find me in app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb\r\n\r\n\r\n----==_mimepart_5534d70b387f1_b853fc04845e6cc9478e\r\nContent-Type: text/html;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n  <body>\r\n    <h1>UserMailer#account_activation</h1>\r\n\r\n<p>\r\n  , find me in app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb\r\n</p>\r\n\r\n  </body>\r\n</html>\r\n\r\n----==_mimepart_5534d70b387f1_b853fc04845e6cc9478e--\r\n".
```

Comment: When you set up a mailer class in rails, using the scaffold or rake task or whatever, it sets the default `from` address to "from@example.com".  Is that not specified at the top of your UserMailer class?

Comment: when i change to "from@example.com", it creates another error

Comment: I have edited the post for the new error.  the last part is the new Failure.

Comment: If you're now asking a completely different question, you should ask a new question on StackOverflow.  It's too confusing otherwise.  However, your problem is that you are asserting that the user's name will match the html-encoded body of the email, and the email body does not contain the user's name.  Does the email template try to render the user's name out at any point?

Comment: I'll make another question.
in anyways, Thank you @MaxWilliams.

Comment: @Max Williams, You might want to answer your first comment so that I can  choose your answer.

Comment: done (padding padding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up a mailer class in rails, using the scaffold or rake task or whatever, it sets the default `from` address to "from@example.com".  This address would normally be specified at the top of your UserMailer class.

Answer (score 0):

You may missed update your
*app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb*

Check sample code in RUBY ON RAILS TUTORIAL
*Listing 10.13: The account activation HTML view.*

Comment: No problem. I just could not find that answer in this post. And I had a same failure. It's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved 2nd question.

Check seeds.rb file. The first user's name maybe not "Michael Example".

Mine was "Example User".